# How long is a keypair valid until an account is funded and created?

Tags: horizon, accounts, ledger, keypair

The documentation says:

> Stellar requires accounts to hold a minimum balance of 1 XLM before they actually exist. Until it gets a bit of funding, your keypair doesn’t warrant space on the ledger.

How long does the end user have to send funds and create their account? What could happen if I provide a public key to an end user and he takes a long time to fund and create his account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: the keypair never expires.

Since the public key is essentially a computational result of so called one-way function, the public key can be derived from the secret key itself. Therefore, the term "keypair" refers to a pair of a secret key and complementary public key that can be regenerated from a secret key. The keypair is generated offline (or at least without touching Stellar network), so the network doesn't know anything about your new keypair until you send a transaction containing `CREATE_ACCOUNT` operation for the public key of this keypair.

When the account is created, Stellar Core servers create a corresponding ledger entry which matches the public key of the keypair. After that we can say that *the account exists on the ledger*. You can even delete the account using `MERGE_ACCOUNT` op and recreate it later using the same keypair.